# Colnames() prints column names in rows, I want single column

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = 1, v2 = 1, v3 = 1)
colnames(df)
```

Returns to the console:

```
> colnames(df)
[1] "v1" "v2" "v3"
```

Instead, I want the printed output to be:

```
[1] "v1"
[2] "v2"
[3] "v3
```

This is so I can copy and paste the printed output into excel to compare column names from multiple dataframes.

Can't see anything in ?colnames() to help. I'm probably missing something really simple.

Comment: _"copy and paste the printed output into excel to compare column names from multiple dataframes"_ Why don't you want to use R for that? Create a list with colnames from all data frames and work with that list. Can you update your question, include a second data frame and show what you want to achieve?

Comment: markus, maybe he have some dificult with R and need to delivery some report kickly. It's not necessary negativate the post, the question is very clear.

Comment: @markus because I'm relatively new to R and doing basic things in R can take ages unless you're an R jedi. As skulden says I need to get this done rapidly and don't have time to start learning about lists at the moment. Agree tho long term I would just do it all in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be

```
writeClipboard(colnames(df))
```

This already copies the names to your clipboard and you can directly insert them (as column) in Excel.

Answer (score 3):

If output to Excel is your goal, I would suggest

```
as.data.frame(colnames(df))
```

Which gives:

```
  colnames(df)
1           v1
2           v2
3           v3
```

If comparing structures of multiple data.frames is your goal, there are many good options to do this with R, the simplest probably to get the "difference" between 2 vectors:

```
setdiff(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "as.matrix" to do this kind of change.

[image]

Comment: also `cbind(colnames(df))`